# SocketIO/NodeJS - Error using socket.emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using the following code:

```js
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(1337);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.emit("error", {title: 'Watch your mouth!', msg: 'Please watch your language, or go to the 18+ chat.'});
  
});
```

and I get the following error:

> Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])
>   Does anyone have any ideas of why this is?

Comment: See [eventEmitter doc here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) for the explanation of the `error` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js has [special handling](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/297b9ae147b590f03597e00d8bb4eee8ea7c347d/lib/events.js#L130) for the `error` event, and will do that if you don't handle it.  (to make sure that uncaught errors don't slip between the cracks)

Choose a different event name.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you!